# Drap and Drop in Eclipse for Web Projects

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Is there an equivalent drag and drop style for Eclipse (or any IDE in Java) for J2EE or JSP that is similar to the IDE feel of ASP.NET in Visual Studio?  ASP.NET allows you to drag and drop controls to a web form or web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Netbeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org/) is the answer of your question. You can design your JSP pages like you are designing Asp.NET pages in Visual Studio. [Here is the link of this feature of Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/web/web-app.html).

[Netbeans Visual Web Design http://www.netbeans.org/images/v6/5/screenshots/visual-web-jsp.png](http://www.netbeans.org/images/v6/5/screenshots/visual-web-jsp.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Visual Studio's capabilities, but Eclipse of course offers visual editors in form of a plugin. Here's an example of a JSP editor (http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-12.html). There are also editors for Swing GUIs etc. Just Google for "visual editor/designer eclipse jsp".

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question this morning, so I downloaded Eclipse and tried to figure it out (I typically use Visual Studio).  Here it is, but it is apparently not nearly as capable as Visual Studio Design View.  Create an HTML file, and then right click on the file and select Web Page Editor.

I learned about it from here, it was difficult to find. http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg13837.html

I would love to see a comparison between VS Design View and Eclipse Web Page Editor; seems like building UIs for the Internet still (after many many years) a mess.

[Screen Shot of Eclipse Web Page Editor](http://www.petegordon.com/eclipse_web_page_editor.jpg)
[Eclipse Web Page Editor http://www.petegordon.com/eclipse_web_page_editor.jpg](http://www.petegordon.com/eclipse_web_page_editor.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Web Pack - http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/ , which provides you with all the resources you need to create a proper page with customizable designed.

You put no restrictions on your IDE, so I can safely say that it is for NetBeans (only build 5.5, however). It is a discontinued project, but whatever is already made, is made to last a while. Strongly suggest.